# Table column spacing / headings

Tags: spacing, longtable

I don't seem to be able to reduce the space between columns with `\setlength\tabcolsep`; it looks like `siunitx` package does not go along with `tabcolsep`.

Further, I'd like to centre the subheadings of the `S` columns which neither seemed to be working with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample No.}`, etc. Column headings 2 to 13 are left aligned and 14 to 22 right aligned.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter paper,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters,linedheaders]{classicthesis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage[nooneline]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}



\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{l*{21}S[table-format=4.5]}
    \caption{Table caption}\\
    \toprule
      &  & & & 
      \multicolumn{8}{c}{CAPTION} & &% 
      \multicolumn{6}{c}{CAPTION (Ma)} &% 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{CAPTION} & &\\
\cmidrule(r){5-12}
\cmidrule(r){14-19}

{Sampel no.} &%
{X (ppm)} &%
{Y (ppm)} &%
{Y/X} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{F}}{^{206}{G}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &% 
{$\frac{^{207}{G}}{^{235}{G}}$} &%    
{$1\sigma$} &% 
{$\frac{^{206}{R}}{^{238}{U}}$}  &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{208}{E}}{^{232}{Th}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\rho$} &%
{$\frac{^{206}{P}}{^{238}{z}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{V}}{^{235}{U}}$}  &%
{1$\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{P}}{^{206}{U}}$}  &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{(Unit)} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\delta$ (\%)} \\
%
\midrule
    \endfirsthead
%
%   
\multicolumn{22}{l}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\  \textit{(Continued)}} \\
%
\toprule
{Sampel no.} &%
{X (ppm)} &%
{Y (ppm)} &%
{Y/X} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{F}}{^{206}{G}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &% 
{$\frac{^{207}{G}}{^{235}{G}}$} &%    
{$1\sigma$} &% 
{$\frac{^{206}{R}}{^{238}{U}}$}  &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{208}{E}}{^{232}{Th}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\rho$} &%
{$\frac{^{206}{P}}{^{238}{z}}$} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{V}}{^{235}{U}}$}  &%
{1$\sigma$} &%
{$\frac{^{207}{P}}{^{206}{U}}$}  &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{(Unit)} &%
{$1\sigma$} &%
{$\delta$ (\%)} \\
\midrule
    \endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{22}{r}{\textit{(Continued)}} \\
    \endfoot
\bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
Sample 1 &        597 &        552 &       0.87 &    0.06641 &    0.00166 &    0.31038 &    0.01076 &    0.03474 &    0.00083 &    0.01092 &    0.00038 &       0.69 &        220 &          5 &        274 &          8 &        819 &         53 &        220 &          5 &       19.7 \\

Sample &        664 &        424 &       0.60 &    0.05545 &    0.00078 &    0.30183 &    0.00577 &    0.03947 &    0.00051 &    0.01292 &    0.00028 &       0.68 &        250 &          3 &        268 &          5 &        430 &         30 &        250 &          3 &        6.7 \\

Sample15\_024 &        634 &        604 &       0.89 &    0.05967 &    0.00449 &    0.33649 &    0.02815 &    0.04090 &    0.00059 &    0.01264 &    0.00016 &       0.45 &        258 &          4 &        295 &         21 &        592 &        158 &        258 &          4 &       12.5 \\
%
Sample2\_009 &         64 &         25 &       0.37 &    0.05609 &    0.00164 &    0.32120 &    0.01034 &    0.04153 &    0.00038 &    0.01293 &    0.00012 &       0.35 &        262 &          2 &        283 &          8 &        456 &         65 &        262 &          2 &        7.4 \\
%
Sample10\_018 &       1124 &        998 &       0.83 &    0.07956 &    0.00103 &    0.45438 &    0.00835 &    0.04195 &    0.00055 &    0.01947 &    0.00091 &       0.71 &        265 &          3 &        380 &          6 &       1186 &         26 &        265 &          3 &       30.3 \\

Sample62\_081 &        113 &         61 &       0.51 &    0.07375 &    0.01142 &    0.43177 &    0.06874 &    0.04246 &    0.00060 &    0.01281 &    0.00031 &       0.15 &        268 &          4 &        364 &         49 &       1035 &        315 &        268 &          4 &       26.4 \\

Sample14\_023 &        536 &         85 &       0.15 &    0.05294 &    0.00069 &    0.33703 &    0.00596 &    0.04608 &    0.00055 &    0.01396 &    0.00024 &       0.68 &        290 &          3 &        295 &          5 &        326 &         30 &        290 &          3 &        1.7 \\

Sample41\_056 &        237 &        106 &       0.42 &    0.05411 &    0.00076 &    0.35000 &    0.00553 &    0.04696 &    0.00034 &    0.01409 &    0.00021 &       0.46 &        296 &          2 &        305 &          4 &        376 &         32 &        296 &          2 &        3.0 \\

Sample72\_092 &        267 &        104 &       0.36 &    0.05328 &    0.00069 &    0.37697 &    0.00560 &    0.05126 &    0.00037 &    0.01616 &    0.00024 &       0.49 &        322 &          2 &        325 &          4 &        341 &         28 &        322 &          2 &        0.9 \\

Sample6\_014 &        720 &        439 &       0.57 &    0.05795 &    0.00064 &    0.47043 &    0.00684 &    0.05899 &    0.00056 &    0.01808 &    0.00029 &       0.65 &        369 &          3 &        391 &          5 &        528 &         23 &        369 &          3 &        5.6 \\

Sample20\_030 &        966 &        180 &       0.18 &    0.06941 &    0.00078 &    0.85861 &    0.01444 &    0.08972 &    0.00086 &    0.02725 &    0.00026 &       0.70 &        554 &          5 &        629 &          8 &        911 &         22 &        554 &          5 &       11.9 \\

Sample68\_088 &         63 &         33 &       0.49 &    0.06329 &    0.00101 &    0.83480 &    0.01490 &    0.09581 &    0.00076 &    0.02805 &    0.00048 &       0.45 &        590 &          4 &        616 &          8 &        718 &         32 &        590 &          4 &        4.2 \\

Sample69\_089 &        503 &        210 &       0.39 &    0.06085 &    0.00061 &    0.80353 &    0.00990 &    0.09579 &    0.00069 &    0.03122 &    0.00044 &       0.58 &        590 &          4 &        599 &          6 &        634 &         21 &        590 &          4 &        1.5 \\

Sample3\_010 &        800 &         71 &       0.08 &    0.06060 &    0.00061 &    0.82852 &    0.01011 &    0.09924 &    0.00069 &    0.03362 &    0.00040 &       0.57 &        610 &          4 &        613 &          6 &        625 &         22 &        610 &          4 &        0.5 \\

Sample34\_047 &        696 &        119 &       0.16 &    0.06577 &    0.00071 &    0.93592 &    0.01397 &    0.10320 &    0.00084 &    0.03154 &    0.00026 &       0.66 &        633 &          5 &        671 &          7 &        799 &         23 &        633 &          5 &        5.7 \\

Sample42\_057 &         73 &         46 &       0.59 &    0.06303 &    0.00113 &    0.90923 &    0.01753 &    0.10475 &    0.00072 &    0.03049 &    0.00043 &       0.37 &        642 &          4 &        657 &          9 &        709 &         38 &        642 &          4 &        2.3 \\

Sample22\_033 &        891 &        283 &       0.30 &    0.07147 &    0.00150 &    1.13515 &    0.02693 &    0.11519 &    0.00093 &    0.03487 &    0.00029 &       0.46 &        703 &          5 &        770 &         13 &        971 &         43 &        703 &          5 &        8.7 \\

Sample11\_020 &        615 &        162 &       0.25 &    0.07379 &    0.00075 &    1.53838 &    0.02019 &    0.15121 &    0.00105 &    0.04561 &    0.00031 &       0.60 &        908 &          6 &        946 &          8 &       1036 &         20 &        908 &          6 &        4.0 \\

Sample45\_060 &        343 &         86 &       0.24 &    0.07127 &    0.00066 &    1.59320 &    0.01913 &    0.16205 &    0.00123 &    0.04709 &    0.00057 &       0.64 &        968 &          7 &        968 &          7 &        965 &         19 &        968 &          7 &        0.0 \\

Sample67\_087 &        178 &         37 &       0.19 &    0.07137 &    0.00090 &    1.60246 &    0.02717 &    0.16284 &    0.00138 &    0.04931 &    0.00041 &       0.60 &        973 &          8 &        971 &         11 &        968 &         24 &        973 &          8 &       -0.2 \\

Sample76\_097 &        184 &         58 &       0.30 &    0.07231 &    0.00072 &    1.72390 &    0.02155 &    0.17290 &    0.00130 &    0.05341 &    0.00069 &       0.60 &       1028 &          7 &       1017 &          8 &        995 &         19 &        995 &         19 &       -1.1 \\

Sample79\_100 &        138 &         55 &       0.37 &    0.07230 &    0.00087 &    1.66670 &    0.02324 &    0.16727 &    0.00119 &    0.04896 &    0.00059 &       0.51 &        997 &          7 &        996 &          9 &        994 &         23 &        997 &          7 &       -0.1 \\

Sample16\_026 &         74 &         32 &       0.41 &    0.07245 &    0.00247 &    1.68496 &    0.06421 &    0.16868 &    0.00153 &    0.05099 &    0.00047 &       0.38 &       1005 &          8 &       1003 &         24 &        999 &         66 &        999 &         66 &       -0.2 \\

Sample80\_101 &        215 &         70 &       0.30 &    0.07302 &    0.00080 &    1.67310 &    0.02173 &    0.16642 &    0.00115 &    0.05004 &    0.00060 &       0.54 &        992 &          6 &        998 &          8 &       1015 &         21 &       1015 &         21 &        0.6 \\

Sample54\_071 &        380 &        111 &       0.28 &    0.07329 &    0.00071 &    1.88310 &    0.02479 &    0.18646 &    0.00166 &    0.05640 &    0.00068 &       0.68 &       1102 &          9 &       1075 &          9 &       1022 &         20 &       1022 &         20 &       -2.5 \\

SampleMH28\_1\_008 &        148 &         57 &       0.36 &    0.07348 &    0.00081 &    1.76520 &    0.02302 &    0.17438 &    0.00122 &    0.05089 &    0.00061 &       0.53 &       1036 &          7 &       1033 &          8 &       1027 &         21 &       1027 &         21 &       -0.3 \\

Sample50\_066 &        518 &         59 &       0.11 &    0.07356 &    0.00066 &    1.70400 &    0.02063 &    0.16811 &    0.00136 &    0.05052 &    0.00066 &       0.67 &       1002 &          8 &       1010 &          8 &       1029 &         18 &       1029 &         18 &        0.8 \\

Sample39\_053 &        161 &         49 &       0.28 &    0.07360 &    0.00088 &    1.68360 &    0.02365 &    0.16586 &    0.00121 &    0.04927 &    0.00059 &       0.52 &        989 &          7 &       1002 &          9 &       1031 &         24 &       1031 &         24 &        1.3 \\

Sample7\_015 &        191 &         22 &       0.11 &    0.07386 &    0.00081 &    2.05020 &    0.04325 &    0.20148 &    0.00363 &    0.05729 &    0.00086 &       0.85 &       1183 &         19 &       1132 &         14 &       1038 &         21 &       1038 &         21 &       -4.5 \\

Sample75\_095 &        115 &         63 &       0.52 &    0.07436 &    0.00097 &    1.76760 &    0.03250 &    0.17284 &    0.00225 &    0.05443 &    0.00147 &       0.70 &       1028 &         12 &       1034 &         12 &       1051 &         25 &       1051 &         25 &        0.6 \\

Sample4\_011 &        313 &        112 &       0.34 &    0.07471 &    0.00102 &    1.64778 &    0.02973 &    0.15997 &    0.00130 &    0.04819 &    0.00038 &       0.59 &        957 &          7 &        989 &         11 &       1061 &         28 &       1061 &         28 &        3.2 \\

Sample46\_062 &         92 &         61 &       0.63 &    0.07483 &    0.00157 &    1.70980 &    0.03796 &    0.16559 &    0.00119 &    0.04824 &    0.00058 &       0.33 &        988 &          7 &       1012 &         14 &       1064 &         43 &       1064 &         43 &        2.4 \\

Sample55\_072 &         46 &         22 &       0.45 &    0.07486 &    0.00112 &    1.68860 &    0.02810 &    0.16368 &    0.00118 &    0.04840 &    0.00063 &       0.44 &        977 &          7 &       1004 &         11 &       1065 &         30 &       1065 &         30 &        2.7 \\

Sample35\_048 &         90 &         24 &       0.25 &    0.07514 &    0.00098 &    1.82660 &    0.02723 &    0.17614 &    0.00129 &    0.05759 &    0.00098 &       0.48 &       1046 &          7 &       1055 &         10 &       1072 &         26 &       1072 &         26 &        0.9 \\

Sample18\_028 &        561 &         85 &       0.14 &    0.07559 &    0.00070 &    1.92580 &    0.02219 &    0.18479 &    0.00126 &    0.05404 &    0.00065 &       0.60 &       1093 &          7 &       1090 &          8 &       1084 &         19 &       1084 &         19 &       -0.3 \\

Sample29\_041 &        175 &         49 &       0.26 &    0.07570 &    0.00091 &    1.85930 &    0.02789 &    0.17804 &    0.00160 &    0.05271 &    0.00074 &       0.60 &       1056 &          9 &       1067 &         10 &       1087 &         24 &       1087 &         24 &        1.0 \\

Sample51\_068 &        261 &         55 &       0.20 &    0.07587 &    0.00074 &    1.89430 &    0.02238 &    0.18110 &    0.00120 &    0.05556 &    0.00067 &       0.56 &       1073 &          7 &       1079 &          8 &       1092 &         20 &       1092 &         20 &        0.6 \\

Sample12\_021 &         76 &         28 &       0.35 &    0.07675 &    0.00137 &    2.00527 &    0.04224 &    0.18950 &    0.00139 &    0.05692 &    0.00041 &       0.41 &       1119 &          8 &       1117 &         14 &       1115 &         34 &       1115 &         34 &       -0.2 \\

Sample57\_075 &        401 &         78 &       0.18 &    0.07679 &    0.00071 &    2.04520 &    0.02418 &    0.19312 &    0.00141 &    0.05962 &    0.00078 &       0.62 &       1138 &          8 &       1131 &          8 &       1116 &         19 &       1116 &         19 &       -0.6 \\

Sample65\_084 &        266 &         74 &       0.26 &    0.07710 &    0.00073 &    1.93020 &    0.02255 &    0.18157 &    0.00123 &    0.05217 &    0.00063 &       0.59 &       1076 &          7 &       1092 &          8 &       1124 &         18 &       1124 &         18 &        1.5 \\

Sample58\_076 &        601 &        159 &       0.25 &    0.07752 &    0.00091 &    1.90717 &    0.02972 &    0.17844 &    0.00146 &    0.05354 &    0.00043 &       0.59 &       1058 &          8 &       1084 &         10 &       1135 &         23 &       1135 &         23 &        2.4 \\

Sample48\_064 &        187 &         55 &       0.28 &    0.07758 &    0.00078 &    1.95780 &    0.02532 &    0.18325 &    0.00150 &    0.05632 &    0.00073 &       0.63 &       1085 &          8 &       1101 &          9 &       1136 &         20 &       1136 &         20 &        1.5 \\

Sample70\_090 &       1088 &        142 &       0.12 &    0.07760 &    0.00065 &    1.94820 &    0.02081 &    0.18211 &    0.00120 &    0.05477 &    0.00071 &       0.62 &       1078 &          7 &       1098 &          7 &       1137 &         16 &       1137 &         16 &        1.8 \\

Sample9\_017 &        707 &         67 &       0.09 &    0.07766 &    0.00072 &    1.98460 &    0.02546 &    0.18535 &    0.00142 &    0.05560 &    0.00042 &       0.62 &       1096 &          8 &       1110 &          9 &       1138 &         17 &       1138 &         17 &        1.3 \\

Sample28\_040 &        236 &         93 &       0.37 &    0.07769 &    0.00071 &    2.10680 &    0.02344 &    0.19631 &    0.00126 &    0.05795 &    0.00070 &       0.57 &       1155 &          7 &       1151 &          8 &       1139 &         18 &       1139 &         18 &       -0.3 \\

Sample32\_045 &        615 &         15 &       0.02 &    0.07771 &    0.00071 &    2.05090 &    0.02447 &    0.19152 &    0.00146 &    0.06149 &    0.00086 &       0.64 &       1130 &          8 &       1133 &          8 &       1139 &         18 &       1139 &         18 &        0.3 \\

Sample66\_086 &        603 &        111 &       0.17 &    0.07769 &    0.00068 &    2.14310 &    0.02462 &    0.20000 &    0.00150 &    0.05516 &    0.00061 &       0.65 &       1175 &          8 &       1163 &          8 &       1139 &         17 &       1139 &         17 &       -1.0 \\

Sample77\_098 &         67 &         39 &       0.55 &    0.07788 &    0.00093 &    2.25830 &    0.03244 &    0.21035 &    0.00166 &    0.06047 &    0.00079 &       0.56 &       1231 &          9 &       1199 &         10 &       1144 &         23 &       1144 &         23 &       -2.7 \\

Sample49\_065 &        259 &         77 &       0.28 &    0.07812 &    0.00078 &    2.08720 &    0.02524 &    0.19377 &    0.00132 &    0.05760 &    0.00069 &       0.56 &       1142 &          7 &       1145 &          8 &       1150 &         20 &       1150 &         20 &        0.3 \\

Sample53\_070 &        241 &         78 &       0.30 &    0.07811 &    0.00105 &    2.04369 &    0.03374 &    0.18976 &    0.00134 &    0.05689 &    0.00039 &       0.50 &       1120 &          7 &       1130 &         11 &       1150 &         27 &       1150 &         27 &        0.9 \\

Sample59\_077 &        566 &         97 &       0.16 &    0.07831 &    0.00071 &    2.18410 &    0.02590 &    0.20262 &    0.00154 &    0.06194 &    0.00081 &       0.64 &       1189 &          8 &       1176 &          8 &       1155 &         18 &       1155 &         18 &       -1.1 \\

Sample63\_082 &        938 &        154 &       0.15 &    0.07832 &    0.00068 &    2.04960 &    0.02315 &    0.18987 &    0.00137 &    0.05157 &    0.00067 &       0.64 &       1121 &          7 &       1132 &          8 &       1155 &         16 &       1155 &         16 &        1.0 \\

Sample44\_059 &       1129 &        233 &       0.19 &    0.07847 &    0.00077 &    1.87500 &    0.03053 &    0.17344 &    0.00225 &    0.04472 &    0.00192 &       0.80 &       1031 &         12 &       1072 &         11 &       1159 &         20 &       1159 &         20 &        3.8 \\

Sample64\_083 &        215 &         68 &       0.30 &    0.07846 &    0.00078 &    2.13130 &    0.02589 &    0.19701 &    0.00136 &    0.05750 &    0.00069 &       0.57 &       1159 &          7 &       1159 &          8 &       1159 &         19 &       1159 &         19 &        0.0 \\

Sample43\_058 &         45 &         32 &       0.67 &    0.07873 &    0.00134 &    2.16880 &    0.04132 &    0.20015 &    0.00172 &    0.05757 &    0.00081 &       0.45 &       1176 &          9 &       1171 &         13 &       1165 &         34 &       1165 &         34 &       -0.4 \\

Sample19\_029 &        206 &         58 &       0.27 &    0.07890 &    0.00077 &    2.25440 &    0.03000 &    0.20735 &    0.00187 &    0.05934 &    0.00077 &       0.68 &       1215 &         10 &       1198 &          9 &       1170 &         19 &       1170 &         19 &       -1.4 \\

Sample17\_027 &       1052 &         39 &       0.03 &    0.07894 &    0.00065 &    2.01476 &    0.02263 &    0.18510 &    0.00154 &    0.05543 &    0.00046 &       0.72 &       1095 &          8 &       1120 &          8 &       1171 &         16 &       1171 &         16 &        2.2 \\

Sample26\_038 &        488 &        140 &       0.27 &    0.07907 &    0.00070 &    2.14030 &    0.02450 &    0.19639 &    0.00141 &    0.05700 &    0.00074 &       0.63 &       1156 &          8 &       1162 &          8 &       1174 &         18 &       1174 &         18 &        0.5 \\

Sample13\_022 &        175 &         41 &       0.22 &    0.07910 &    0.00079 &    2.32380 &    0.03095 &    0.21300 &    0.00187 &    0.06711 &    0.00114 &       0.66 &       1245 &         10 &       1220 &          9 &       1175 &         20 &       1175 &         20 &       -2.0 \\

Sample37\_051 &         31 &         14 &       0.44 &    0.07957 &    0.00127 &    2.11760 &    0.03973 &    0.19307 &    0.00189 &    0.06030 &    0.00096 &       0.53 &       1138 &         10 &       1155 &         13 &       1186 &         32 &       1186 &         32 &        1.5 \\

Sample74\_094 &         66 &         37 &       0.52 &    0.07966 &    0.00112 &    2.20670 &    0.03526 &    0.20105 &    0.00155 &    0.05839 &    0.00076 &       0.48 &       1181 &          8 &       1183 &         11 &       1189 &         26 &       1189 &         26 &        0.2 \\

Sample73\_093 &        370 &         86 &       0.22 &    0.07978 &    0.00076 &    2.12390 &    0.02481 &    0.19272 &    0.00131 &    0.05831 &    0.00082 &       0.58 &       1136 &          7 &       1157 &          8 &       1192 &         18 &       1192 &         18 &        1.8 \\

Sample27\_039 &        925 &        231 &       0.23 &    0.07983 &    0.00069 &    2.00430 &    0.02130 &    0.18210 &    0.00111 &    0.05542 &    0.00061 &       0.58 &       1078 &          6 &       1117 &          7 &       1193 &         17 &       1193 &         17 &        3.5 \\

Sample56\_074 &        935 &        270 &       0.27 &    0.07986 &    0.00079 &    1.64890 &    0.04587 &    0.14818 &    0.00385 &    0.04640 &    0.00097 &       0.93 &        891 &         22 &        989 &         18 &       1194 &         20 &       1194 &         20 &        9.9 \\

Sample52\_069 &        339 &         92 &       0.26 &    0.08018 &    0.00078 &    2.20630 &    0.02614 &    0.19963 &    0.00136 &    0.05742 &    0.00069 &       0.57 &       1173 &          7 &       1183 &          8 &       1201 &         19 &       1201 &         19 &        0.8 \\

Sample60\_078 &        153 &         54 &       0.33 &    0.08037 &    0.00080 &    2.40630 &    0.02937 &    0.21715 &    0.00152 &    0.05705 &    0.00068 &       0.58 &       1267 &          8 &       1244 &          9 &       1206 &         19 &       1206 &         19 &       -1.8 \\

Sample40\_054 &        776 &         59 &       0.07 &    0.08042 &    0.00075 &    2.31440 &    0.02736 &    0.20887 &    0.00152 &    0.06238 &    0.00081 &       0.61 &       1223 &          8 &       1217 &          8 &       1207 &         19 &       1207 &         19 &       -0.5 \\

Sample78\_099 &        889 &        122 &       0.13 &    0.08091 &    0.00074 &    2.27562 &    0.03090 &    0.20399 &    0.00168 &    0.06092 &    0.00051 &       0.67 &       1197 &          9 &       1205 &         10 &       1219 &         17 &       1219 &         17 &        0.7 \\

Sample31\_044 &        975 &         67 &       0.06 &    0.08101 &    0.00072 &    1.72390 &    0.01931 &    0.15423 &    0.00105 &    0.03562 &    0.00057 &       0.61 &        925 &          6 &       1017 &          7 &       1222 &         18 &       1222 &         18 &        9.0 \\

Sample36\_050 &        656 &         76 &       0.11 &    0.08140 &    0.00072 &    2.21600 &    0.02496 &    0.19758 &    0.00136 &    0.06002 &    0.00066 &       0.62 &       1162 &          7 &       1186 &          8 &       1231 &         17 &       1231 &         17 &        2.0 \\

Sample23\_034 &        317 &         95 &       0.28 &    0.08145 &    0.00075 &    2.45010 &    0.02862 &    0.21820 &    0.00157 &    0.06418 &    0.00071 &       0.62 &       1272 &          8 &       1257 &          8 &       1232 &         18 &       1232 &         18 &       -1.2 \\

Sample25\_036 &        165 &         52 &       0.29 &    0.08160 &    0.00082 &    2.30110 &    0.03254 &    0.20452 &    0.00205 &    0.06704 &    0.00080 &       0.70 &       1200 &         11 &       1213 &         10 &       1236 &         20 &       1236 &         20 &        1.1 \\

Sample61\_080 &        406 &        279 &       0.65 &    0.08182 &    0.00074 &    2.26150 &    0.02592 &    0.20045 &    0.00142 &    0.05558 &    0.00067 &       0.61 &       1178 &          8 &       1200 &          8 &       1241 &         17 &       1241 &         17 &        1.8 \\

Sample33\_046 &        252 &         88 &       0.33 &    0.08227 &    0.00082 &    2.39580 &    0.02938 &    0.21130 &    0.00150 &    0.06177 &    0.00074 &       0.58 &       1236 &          8 &       1241 &          9 &       1252 &         20 &       1252 &         20 &        0.4 \\

Sample21\_032 &        465 &        311 &       0.63 &    0.08380 &    0.00071 &    2.41950 &    0.02619 &    0.20946 &    0.00140 &    0.06111 &    0.00067 &       0.62 &       1226 &          7 &       1248 &          8 &       1288 &         16 &       1288 &         16 &        1.8 \\

Sample38\_052 &        258 &         88 &       0.32 &    0.08480 &    0.00078 &    2.53110 &    0.03053 &    0.21619 &    0.00169 &    0.06193 &    0.00074 &       0.65 &       1262 &          9 &       1281 &          9 &       1311 &         18 &       1311 &         18 &        1.5 \\

Sample81\_103 &        165 &         70 &       0.40 &    0.08491 &    0.00085 &    2.48350 &    0.03308 &    0.21223 &    0.00187 &    0.06244 &    0.00069 &       0.66 &       1241 &         10 &       1267 &         10 &       1313 &         18 &       1313 &         18 &        2.1 \\

Sample47\_063 &        643 &        195 &       0.28 &    0.09016 &    0.00144 &    1.56680 &    0.06750 &    0.12936 &    0.00517 &    0.07140 &    0.00193 &       0.93 &        784 &         30 &        957 &         27 &       1429 &         29 &       1429 &         29 &       18.1 \\

Sample24\_035 &        357 &         63 &       0.16 &    0.09045 &    0.00089 &    2.29137 &    0.04104 &    0.18373 &    0.00234 &    0.05422 &    0.00068 &       0.82 &       1087 &         13 &       1210 &         13 &       1435 &         19 &       1435 &         19 &       10.2 \\

Sample30\_042 &         87 &         27 &       0.29 &    0.10088 &    0.00111 &    4.01770 &    0.05946 &    0.28855 &    0.00286 &    0.08544 &    0.00120 &       0.67 &       1634 &         14 &       1638 &         12 &       1640 &         19 &       1640 &         19 &        0.2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please in future try to limit packages and fonts needed in an example. However the space is not *between* the columns it is *in* the columns as you have formatted each for 5 decimal places and four integer places even if the column does not need it.

Fir example if you use

```
  \begin{longtable}{lS[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=1.2]*{18}S[table-format=4.5]}
```

The first three columns use better spacing, you need to choose an appropriate format for each column.